# How to load multiple fxml files in a SplitPane, which is inside a BorderPane

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have got a RootLayout which consists of a BorderPane and inside of that is a SplitPane (split horizontally) and on the right side of the splitPane again a SplitPane (Split vertically).

I'd like to load 3 different FXML files each in one of the empty SplitPane halfs (one on the left, one on the upper right side and one on the lower right side).

Is that possible or should I create a BorderPane, in which I load FXML SplitPanes in which I then load my finally used FXML files?